# remove duplicated values form numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have three numpy arrays

```
x =np.array([1,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,3,3])
y =np.array([10,20,30,40,20,10,20,30,39,39])
z =np.array([100,200,300,400,200,100,200,300,300,300])
```

I want to check if x[i]==x[j] and y[i]==y[j] and z[i]!=z[j]. If this is true I want to remove z[j].

In pseudo code:

```
label: check
for i in range(0,np.size(x)):
  for j in range(0,np.size(x)):
    If x[i] == x[j] and y[i]==y[j] and z[i]!=z[j] and i<j:
      x = delete(x,j)
      y = delete(y,j)
      z = delete(z,j)
      print "start again from above"
      goto check
```

Since I use  goto and I don't know any other way around this I want to ask if there is any quick and elegant way to do this (maybe based on numpy predefined functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
np.unique(np.array([x, y, z]), axis=1)
```